# getting all the data in the table using ajax with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im having trouble on how to solve this problem

[image]

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#submit').click(function (){
         var username = $('#username').val();
         var msg = $('#msg').val();

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'get.php',
             dataType: 'json',
             data:'username='+username+'&msg='+msg,
             success: function (data){
                 $.each(data, function(i) {
                     $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data[i].mesg);
                 });​
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

still trying to solve it but im running out of luck

Comment: PHP is not generating your data properly, do `data[i].username` is probably undefined in your JS-side data as well.

Comment: You're using `msg` in one place and `mesg` in another. Is this intentional?

Comment: I don't thnk this is a jQuery or javascript problem. Look at what your PHP is returning.

Comment: my php is like this:$get = "SELECT * FROM info ";

$result=mysql_query($get)or die(mysql_error()); 


$data=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $data[] = array(
    'username'=>$row['user_name'],
    'mesg'=>$row['message']
 );
}
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: add an error handler and `console.log(arguments[0].responseText);` within it. What does the console show?

Answer (score 0):

Data attribute has to sent as an Json Object

```
data:'username='+username+'&msg='+msg,
```

Which you are not doing .. try this way

```
data:{ 'username' : username , 'msg' : msg}
```

And how does the returned json object look like..
Does it have two keys called **username** and **mseg** ??

Comment: Actually he has the correct number of `});`; it just didnt appear like it initially. I have edited his code so it is more readable.

Comment: i checked it again but i guess there is no extra }); still having the illegal character error<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#submit').click(function (){
     var username = $('#username').val();
      var msg = $('#msg').val();
     $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'get.php',
dataType: 'json',
data:{ 'username' : username , 'msg' : msg}, 
success: function (data){
$.each(data, function(i,item) {

                     $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data[i].mesg);
                   });​
}
});
  });
</script>

Comment: Do you have the opening script tag.. Also missing an extra });  for document.ready

Comment: i checked it but here's the entire script :<script>
$(document).ready(function (){

     


  $('#submit').click(function (){
     var username = $('#username').val();
      var msg = $('#msg').val();

     $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'get.php',
dataType: 'json',
data:{ 'username' : username , 'msg' : msg}, 
success: function (data){
 $.each(data, function(i,item) {

                     $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data[i].mesg);
                   });​
                }
            });

  });


</script>

Comment: How does your data jSon object looks like after it is returned

Comment: Is it an array of objects..?? [{} , {} , {} ]

Answer (score 0):

Data should be written as a JSON object:

```
data: {'username': username, 'msg':msg},
```

Comment: `JSON` -> `JavaScript`, and changing from a string representation to an object representation won't change the outcome, an object would end up being passed to `jQuery.param()` turning it into a param string.

Comment: Didn't know that about jQuery.param(), but he should still use object notation to stop that function call

Answer (score 0):

try changing the query line to `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` and then see if the rest of the code works.